# No PDF bookmarks when using llncs class

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, lncs

When using hyperref together with Springer's LNCS class ([llncs](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0)), only the title of the document shows up in the PDF bookmarks.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Foobar}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

When you compile this document, the only entry in the PDF bookmarks is one for "Foobar" (which shouldn't be there) and there are no entries for the sections.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

I'm using TeX Live 2011 and llncs 2.17.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this behaviour is intended. The [llncs document class](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip) is used to put multiple articles into one volume. Each article title appears in the table of contents and the pdf bookmarks, but sections within the articles do not.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%
\title{Sheep}
\maketitle
\section{Black sheep}
\section{White sheep}
%
\title{Goats}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to employ `llncs` for your personal use, then

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\llncs@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\addcontentsline}{\llncs@addcontentsline}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\addcontentsline}{\llncs@addcontentsline}{}{}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\addcontentsline}{\llncs@addcontentsline}{}{}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
```

will remove the bookmarks for author and title, while giving those for sections and subsections.

Comment: That's what I needed! But somehow, I didn't get author bookmarks, and I only needed `tocdepth`. That's with llncs 2.18 released last week, but they don't document related changes.

Comment: The history.txt from `llncs2e.zip` says that version 2.15 (from March 2010) “fixed broken hyperref interoperability.” So `tocdepth` is probably the only necessary thing now.

Comment: Note that three patches are necessary in order to replace *all* occurrences of `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is exactly what I needed to generate bookmarks in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02138) with `documentclass` as `llncs`