# PDF bookmarks for sections and subsections with the llncs class

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks, lncs

The following code is in the preamble of my LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[algoruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue}


\numberwithin{equation}{section} % numbering according to the section
\bibliographystyle{plain}  %Choose a bibliograhpic style
\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\maketitle
\section{A}
\label{sect:A}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\section{B}
\label{sect:B}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\section{C}
\label{sect:C}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\end{document}
```

Note that the text is organized into sections and subsection. However, after compiling the code, the Adobe PDF preview does not show the "tree" branching on the left. Instead, it just shows "The Title", and that option has no branching with the "+/-" sings. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please always add a full but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and makes it possible to recreate it. I added some dummy `\section`s and `\subsection`s here. Please have a look if it is right.

Comment: The `llncs` class can be found at http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0 if someone wants to compile the example.

Comment: Thanks. I edited to emphasize that the     \label    is also used. So?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible have the PDF bookmark level go deeper that the table of contents depth?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18743/2975)

Comment: See also [No PDF bookmarks when using llncs class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47383) for other possible problems with `llncs`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `llncs` class sets `tocdepth` to 0. This setting controls which sectioning commands end up in the Table-Of-Contents (TOC), which is also used by `hyperref` for the PDF bookmarks depth by default. You need to set the `bookmarksdepth` manually to a higher value (higher means more deeper sectioning commands are included). An alternative is to raise `tocdepth` again, but this also affects the `\tableofcontents` command, which might be unwanted.

Here are correctly working example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[bookmarks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\title{The Title}
\author{the author}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%  alternative (2 or higher)
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A}
\label{sect:A}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\section{B}
\label{sect:B}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\section{C}
\label{sect:C}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
% ...
\end{document}
```

---

A list of all depth numbers for the sectioning commands can be found in [How to show subsections and subsubsections in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17879/2975)

Comment: Works, thanks. It was the `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` command.

Comment: @boy: Note that I updated the answer. Using `bookmarksdepth=2` (or higher) does it also and might be better.

Comment: thanks. I found that `\subsubsection{a}` doesn't show when setting `bookmarksdepth=3`. Is that just me?

Comment: @Tim: Are you using the `llncs` class like above or another one? The sectioning depth depends on the class. `book` style classes start to count at `\chapter` while `article` like classes start at `\section`.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! :D
Helped me generate bookmarks for a lot of Arxiv papers which weren't working